# Adding multiple images,svg's in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to add svg's into the textarea. Fortunately it works my textarea can add as "text" and then the svg is visible where I want it. But the problem is that I cannot put multiple times, every time I press for adding them, one replaces the other.Will never be like "text""text" etc etc.

Here is my javascript code

```
function test() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "cloudda3.php",
        success: function(result) {
            $("#comment").val('<img src="emoticons/cloudda3.svg">');
        }
    })
}
```

How can I send multiple times the value to the textarea for anytime I will press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't add it multiple times is because you are overwriting the value each time. Instead, you need to *append* to the current value of `#comment`:

```
$("#comment").val($("#comment").val() +'<img src="emoticons/cloudda3.svg">');
```

Here we add the svg onto the current value of `#comment`, and only after we have done that do we update `#comment`'s value.

Comment: Done! Thank you!

Comment: @L-DracWarThorn no worries, glad to help :D